# Reset button is working before form submission but not after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, forms

I created a form which consists of submit and reset button. Reset button is working fine before the form submission. Once the form is submitted, my View consists some values which got pre-populated. After submitting the form if it has any error messages it is displayed using ModelState.AddError() method. Now if i hitting the Reset button the values are not getting cleared.

I tried using JQuery like

```
 $("#reset_button").click(function() {
                $("#InterviewerName").val("");
                $("#ContactName").val("");
});
```

But it's not working. Any Ideas?

Here is my Buttons in the form

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" style="height:30px; width:85px; border:none; text-align:center; background-color:#06266F;cursor:pointer;color:white" /> 
    @Html.Raw("&nbsp;")
    <input type ="reset" id ="reset_button", value ="Reset" style="height:30px; width:85px; text-align:center; border:none; background-color:#06266F;cursor:pointer;color:white"/>
```

Comment: why arent you using a button of type reset? Are those really input vals or the attribute "value"? Is there a placeholder attribute?

Comment: @Alex I used the button of type Reset only. Added the code in my question

Comment: show the whole form please and/or make a fiddle

Comment: @Alex That was a very big View, so i just pasted the code that was going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
var form = $("#myForm");

form
    .on({
        submit : function() {
            //handle form submit

            //assuming it's an ajax call otherwise ignore
            return false;
        },
        reset : function() {
            // handle form reset
            $("#InterviewerName").val("");
            $("#ContactName").val("");

            //assuming it's an ajax call otherwise ignore
            return false;

        }
    });
```

form submit and reset event handlers belong to the form

also i would recommend you move your css to a file if it's not generated by javascript which is also not a good idea

Answer (score 1):

Use this Jquery function:

```
$.fn.clearForm = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var type = this.type, tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
            if (tag == 'form')
                return $(':input',this).clearForm();
            if (type == 'text' || type == 'password' || tag == 'textarea')
                this.value = '';
            else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio')
                this.checked = false;
            else if (tag == 'select')
                this.selectedIndex = -1;
        });
    };
```

and call this function by using :

```
  $("#reset_button").click(function(){

      $('#login').clearForm();
  });
```

Comment: This code works, but what I don't like is it iterates through all form controls  which is scary.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the reset type button like so

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prP2d/)

### Edit

Here is a sample of code that will empty all the values of your inputs

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reset_button").on('click', function() {
        $('#myForm').find('input').each(function() {
            $(this).val('');
        });
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fLq9A/)

Comment: This will work before the form submission only. I want to make it work after the form is submitted

Comment: I tried this one too, its not replacing the values of InterviewerName and ContactName, rather its clearing the text from the buttons. that means the values submit and reset is cleared but not the textboxes

Comment: Could you please update your question with the entire HTML code of your form?